# Publishing an NServiceBus 4 event from a windows forms application

Tags: c#, nservicebus, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to write a test harness to send NServiceBus commands and events.  I've managed to get it to send commands, and it happily calls publish, but it doesn't handle subscription requests when the app starts up so the publish call doesn't actually send any messages.
How do I tell NServiceBus to process the subscription requests when I initialise the Bus?
Here's the initialisation code so far:

```
               Bus = Configure.With(LoadAssemblies())
                .DefaultBuilder()
                .UnicastBus()
                .ImpersonateSender(true)
                .DefiningCommandsAs(AllValidCommands)
                .DefiningMessagesAs(AllValidMessages)
                .DefiningEventsAs(AllValidEvents)
                .RavenSubscriptionStorage()
                .CreateBus();
```

Comment: Is this all your configuration code? Looks like you're not starting the bus, only creating it.

Comment: What transport and persister are you using? Are subscriptions being received? Are subscriptions stored? Are they stored in-memory, but lost after restart? And _what_ is it exactly you're testing?

Comment: That's just the bus configuration code.  The bus is started before use and can send commands.  I'm using MSMQ as transport and RavenDB as persister.  The subscription requests are in the test harness queue but the test harness doesn't process them.  I'm testing a number of windows services that run NserviceBus.Host.Exe and load our endpoint dlls.

Comment: It's hard with only this configuration code to tell what's going on. Contact support@particular.net if you want to discuss it further. We can always provide the answer on SO later. Also, the reason I'm asking what you're testing is because you likely should not test if MSMQ is working, for example.

Answer (score -1):

In case of Pub/sub mode, you need to make sure, you run Publisher first & then subscribe .... check these link http://dennis.bloggingabout.net/2015/10/28/nservicebus-publish-subscribe-tutorial/